# Why are most sensors designed to operate on a low voltage?

Tags: power-supply, sensor, embedded

I took a look at sensor boards from Adafruit and Embeddio SNAP Boards and I've noticed that most of those boards use sensors that operate on a fairly low voltage of 3V3.

Is there a specific reason why most sensors are designed to operate on a low voltage?
If there is a specific advantage of operating it on 3V3 instead of 5V, then why not go even lower?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! In order to make interfacing with popular MCUs easy. I/O voltages of CPUs, MCUs, CPLDs and FPGAs is constantly going down in the quest for lower power and cost. 5 V is becoming obsolete and 3.3 V is being standard at the moment but 2.5 V is soon taking over.

Comment: I would imagine that most of the adafruit sensor products will operate on voltages also higher than 3.3 volts - can you justify your opening sentence? I can't justify it and I've had a look a few minutes ago. Maybe provide a link to an adafruit sensor category where you saw this?

Comment: @winny Thank you! Do you think power consumption plays a role?

Comment: In the sensor? Sure, but the driving factor is die area cost and losses inside whatever MCU/FPGA is interfacing towards said sensor.

Comment: @Andyaka Indeed not all of the boards but most of the boards I've seen operate on 3V3 (like MEMS sensors), I've changed the sentence :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the Raspberry Pi has 3.3V GPIOs. And that one is defining that whole class of devices.

You will hardly find embedded computer boards with 5V GPIOs nowadays. Some even have 1.8V GPIOs.

Answer (score 0):

Most sensors are designed to operate at low voltages especially in the 3.3V range because they are designed to be battery compatible. Lithium ion cells have a nominal voltage of 3.6V. Therefore when these sensors are coupled with a microcontroller, they can serve their purpose with just a single cell lithium battery.

If they were designed for 5V then two lithium ion cells need to be connected in series and low drop out regulator might be necessary.